# Amount Field Length Extension: Code Adaptations (2 decimals / 3 decimals)

Tags: abap, s4hana

While preparing for the conversion to S/4HANA, our custom code check produces following error message:

> Old Arithmetic type conflict (Type DMBTR, Note: 0002610650) P(13,3)

I have recreated the problem in a simple demo program.

```
DATA: punit TYPE dmbtr,                 "curr(23,2)
      two   TYPE dmbtr VALUE '12.55',   "curr(23,2)
      three TYPE menge_d VALUE '5.123'. "quan(13,3)
CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS arithmetic_errors = 4.
  punit = two / three.
ENDCATCH.
WRITE (26) punit.
```

The error is in the line `punit = two / three.`

I've already checked the SAP Note [2610650](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2610650) but can not find any useful information in it. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new data type `dmbtr_cs` it worked fine. (see SAP Note [2628040](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2628040))

```
DATA: punit TYPE dmbtr_cs,
      two   TYPE dmbtr_cs VALUE '12.55',
      three TYPE menge_d VALUE '5.123'.

CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS arithmetic_errors = 4.
  punit = two / three.
ENDCATCH.

WRITE (26) punit.
```